# Why does Watir WebDriver need regex to find text unless path to tag is specified?

Tags: html, regex, watir-webdriver

I have a table that is being very difficult to work with in terms of finding elements using Watir WebDriver. Here is a screen shot of the table:

[image]

In order to check the box next to "Email: " I am first searching for the email text, using .parent to go up to the `tr` tag, then down to the `checkbox`.

The tricky thing is locating the "Email: " text on the screen.

Note the following observations:

1. The text inside the `label` tag includes a space after the colon. `<label for="enabledEmail17">Email: </label>`
2. This works: `browser.div(:aria_labelledby, 'ui-id-74').label(:text, 'Email:').present?
   => true`
3. This does not work: `browser.label(:text, 'Email:').present?
   => false`
4. This does not work: `browser.label(:text, 'Email: ').present?
   => false`
5. This works but is extremely slow: `browser.label(:text, /Email:/).present?
   => true`

The problem is that I cannot use the parent `div(:aria_labelledby, 'ui-id-74')` to help locate the desired row because the `ui-id` number changes for each "Lessee" in my database. (For the same reason I cannot use the checkbox `id` `enabledEmail17` or any other numbered attribute on the page.) And while using a regex will work as shown above, it takes Watir Webdriver about 2 minutes to fill out the form (vs under 10 seconds without a regex).

So the question is, why do #2 and #5 above work while #3 and #4 do not? I will add that all the other tables for the other Lessees are hidden in the HTML for this page, but given that #5 works as desired, I don't think this is the problem. Plus, I am getting `false` returned; the problem is not that I am finding the wrong element.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Here is a relevant portion of HTML:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 600px; top: 59px; left: 497px; display: block; z-index: 102;" aria-describedby="ttDefaultRoleDialog17" aria-labelledby="ui-id-74">

<table class="ui-widget-content po-widget-content fullWidth">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td class="bold ttBrandedCBTD">Branded</td>
      <td class="bold">Information</td>
      <td class="bold">Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ttBrandedCBTD"></td>
      <td><label>Role: </label></td>
      <td>Lessee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="center ttBrandedCBTD"><input type="checkbox" id="enabledEmail17" class="enableRoleField" data-field-class="aliasEmail"></td>
      <td>
      <span class="required-red required-info-toggle eo-hidden">*</span><label for="enabledEmail17">Email: </label></td>
      <td>
<div id="wwgrp_email17" class="wwgrp text-left align-left">


<div id="wwctrl_email17" class="wwctrl">
<input type="email" name="roleMappings[17].email" maxlength="255" value="" id="email17" class="singleUser role-info aliasEmail addressBook ui-autocomplete-input" data-index="17" data-invalid-email="mapusers.email.valid" autocomplete="off"></div> </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody></table>

</div>
```

Comment: When I try your code against the HTML sample, I get `true`, `true`, `false`, `true`, which is what I would expect. I think you need to share more HTML.

Comment: Well, that's frustrating. I had to ask permission to post the HTML I did put up here and the full HTML for the page is nearly 18000 lines. I'm not sure I'll be allowed to post more, and I am at a loss regarding where the problem is coming from so I wouldn't know what would be the key part of the page to show you. Do any ideas come to mind? Also, why is it that you would expect `false` from the third statement when the `label` element does contain the trailing space?

Comment: The third statement should be `false` because Watir compares against the text with the spaces normalized, which includes stripping the leading/trailing whitespace. In other words, it looks for "Email: ", but the element's text is considered to be "Email:".

Comment: Gotcha. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: I think the only way to get that set of results is if there are multiple labels with that text and the first one is hidden. What do you get if you do `browser.labels(:text, 'Email:').count`?

Comment: There are 52. Perhaps it's the hidden fields that are confounding things. I find it interesting that `browser.label(:text, /Email:/).present?` works. Maybe with a regex Watir will continue to search the entire page for a possible `true` value, while searching with quoted text will jump out of the search on the first result.

Comment: Are there multiple of these roles tables on the page? Given the `div` class, it sounds like it is a dialog box. Is the dialog in the HTML for each role displayed on the page? The reason the regular expression works is because it compares against the visible text. For the labels that are hidden, they are not considered to have text and therefore do not get matched. This is a [known issue that is being discussed](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/342).

Comment: Yes, each of the "Email:" labels is in a roles table, so there are 52 tables in the HTML (at least 51 hidden at any given time). Your replies clear this up for me, and thanks for the link to the Watir WebDriver issues page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The behaviours observed are due to the page containing multiple labels with the same text. These behaviours can be seen with the page simplified to:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <label style="display:none;">Email: </label>
    <div aria-labelledby="ui-id-74">
      <label>Email: </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Running the same examples:

```
browser.div(:aria_labelledby, 'ui-id-74').label(:text, 'Email:').present?
#=> true

browser.label(:text, 'Email:').present?
#=> false

browser.label(:text, 'Email: ').present?
#=> false

browser.label(:text, /Email:/).present?
#=> true
```

This behaviour is expected because:

1. For the second scenario: Watir returns the first matching element, which, in this case, is not displayed. Since the `present?` method checks that the element exists and is visible, `false` is expected.
2. For the third scenario: Watir normalizes the space in the text being compared against. In other words, Watir considers the label's text to actually be "Email:". This is why the element will never be found.
3. For the fourth scenario: When matching text against a regular expression, Watir checks against the visible text. The first label has no visible text and therefore does not get matched. As a result, you get the second label. This is a [known issue that is currently being discussed].

**Solution**

You need to find a way to differentiate the visible fields from the hidden fields. From the HTML, it looks like each table is displayed like a dialog, but with only one displayed at a time. I would try isolating the locating to the visible dialog.

Try:

```
dialog = browser.divs(:class, 'ui-dialog').find(&:visible?)
dialog.label(:text, 'Email:').present?
```

It looks like the dialogs might be generated by jQueryUI, which means you might be able to avoid iterating through the dialogs by inspecting the style attribute:

```
dialog = browser.div(:css, 'div.ui-dialog[style*="display: block;"]')
dialog.label(:text, 'Email:').present?
```

Note that instead of iterating from the label to the checkbox, you can use the `:label` locator:

```
dialog.checkbox(:label, 'Email:').present?
```

Comment: In its final implementation, this works quite quickly and nicely: `grandparent = browser.labels(:text, 'Email:').find(&:visible?).parent.parent` then `grandparent.checkbox.set` and `grandparent.td(:index => 2).text_field.set 'test@test.com'`. Thanks again!